# Access notification within webview

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I just started using cordova for a web app I built, I am currently building the cordova app with the following

```
<script>window.location.assign('http://192.168.1.11/projects/1/backbone/app/')</script>
```

Can some one tell me if it is possible for me to call the following within my web app so that it affects the phones state?

```
navigator.notification.vibrate(2500);
```

If so what am I doing wrong or can you point me in the right direction.